# Video crashes whenever I play a video in youtube

Tags: video, internet, youtube

Whenever I play a video in Youtube, the clip plays for several seconds until unexpectedly crashing with an error "An error has occurred. Please try again later". This only happens when playing videos in Youtube, and does not occur in other video-related sites. Why is this happening?

Comment: What browser are you on? IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari? And what operating system are you on? -Have you tried another browser and do the error continue there? -or to reinstall the current browser?

Comment: I am using windows 7 with Firefox. Interestingly, the same problem also occurs when I switch to Chrome or IE.

Comment: I actually expirenced something like that once on IE... Disappeared once I upgraded/re-downloaded adobe flashplayer. Try give that a go...

Comment: I double-checked and my flash player is up-to-date. I already ruled this out as the cause of my problem but double-checked to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try uninstalling and re-installing Flash from your computer and see whether that resolves your problem. There sometimes is a bug in Adobe Flash when updating from one version to the next. This may have been your problem.